# Redirect to controller if query in model return empty in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

what I want to do is redirect user to another controller if query in my model return empty.

I have controller like this, passing url parameter in $id to get specific user

```html
public function get_user($id)
{
  $data['user'] = $this->user_model->get_user_detail($id);
  $this->load->view('customer_detail',$data);
}
```

And my model :

```html
public function get_user_detail($id)
{
  $query = $this->db->where('user_id', $id)->get('user');
    return $query->row();
}
```

then I passed the result to my view like this:

```html
<?php echo $user->name;?>
```

It's worked just fine. The url from my controller will be something like mysite/user/get_user/7 and '7' is the id. But if I typed non existent id directly in the url bar like mysite/user/get_user/99 it will throw error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" because there are no user with id 99 in the database. How to redirect user to another controller if there is no data found from the query?

Thanks

Comment: why another controller? I would either load the customer_detail view or load a 404 view if data['user'] is empty

Comment: @vickel Ah, yes of course. I tried to check the result in the model then redirect. It's not working. I should do checking the data['user'] on the controler and just load another view if it's empty. It's worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Vickel for pointing out. I should do the checking on the controller not in the model and don't need redirect. I was do the checking on the model and redirect.

```html
public function get_user($id)
{
  $data['user'] = $this->user_model->get_user_detail($id);
  if (!empty($data['user'])) {
  $this->load->view('customer_detail',$data);
  } else {
  $this->load->view('404');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to redirect.

```
$q =  $this->db->query()->row();
 If($q==""){
   redirect('url/page');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_user_detail($id)
{
  $query = $this->db->where('user_id', $id)->get('user');
    $query != "" ? redirect('actual-controller ($query)') : redirect('other-controller');
}
```

`controller($query){ return $query->row(); //your view code for view here }`